# c++, I am making a program that counts how many time a letter appears in a file

Tags: c++, file

It should be stated that we are also checking for the longest word involving that letter as well as the shortest word.

it should be stated that I'm a student and my code has a few errors

WARNING: LACK OF COMMENTS also it should be stated that I had no clue what I was doing while making this due to vague instructions given by the teacher
my code; word.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
#include"myStrCharFunc.h"
using namespace std;

const int SIZE=26; //Size of the area, one for each letter
const int MAX=30; //Size of the c string that will store word from the input file

typedef char cstr[MAX];

struct let
 {
   int count;//nummber of words that start with thr letter
   int shortest;
   int longest;
 };

void initializeArray(let ar[]);
void readData(let ar[]);
void processWord(cstr word, let ar[]);

int main()
 {
   //cstr s="Hi";
   let ar[SIZE];

   return 0;
 }

void initializeArray(let ar[])
 {
   for(int i=0;i<SIZE; i++)
    {
      ar[i].count=0;
      ar[i].shortest=9999;
      ar[i].longest=0;
    }
 }

void readData(let ar[])
 {
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("project2.dat");
  if(!fin)
   {
     cout<<"Your input file doesn't exist"<<endl;
   }
  else
   {

     //let temp;
     //fin>>temp.count;
     //fin>>temp.shortest;
     //fin>>temp.longest;
     cstr word=" ";
     fin>>word;
     while(fin)
      {
        processWord(word, ar);
        fin>>word;
      }
   }
 fin.close();
}

void processWord(cstr word, let ar[])
 {

  for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
    ar[i].count++;
    myToUpper(word);
    int fev = myStrLen(word);
    if(ar[i].longest < fev)
      {
        ar[i].longest = fev;
      }
    if(ar[i].shortest > fev)
     }
       ar[i].shortest=fev;
     }

}
```

the other program connected to this; myStrCharFunc.h

```
 //myToUpper('a')-->'A'
//myToUpper('A')-->'A'
char myToUpper(char b)
 {

   if('a'<= b && b <= 'z')
    {
      b-=('a'-'A');
    }
   return b;
 }

int myStrLen(const char cstr[])
 {
  int i=0;
  for(i; cstr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    ;
  return i;

 }
```

myToUpper was suppose to take in a character or C-String and use the ASCII table to make it a capital letter

Meanwhile myStrLen was suppose to record the length of each individual word it takes in.

The errors for the code I wrote are:

> word.cpp: In function ‘void processWord(char*, let*)’: word.cpp:77:21:
>   error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
>    myToUpper(word);
>                  ^ In file included from word.cpp:6:0:  myStrCharFunc.h:3:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char
> ```
>
> myToUpper(char)’ [-fpermissive]  char myToUpper(char b)

/*It should be stated that none of the code I wrote in here was properly formatted after pressing CTRL+K and cutting and pasting it in the given area so it was all done by hand*/

Also the file we are using; project2.dat contains only this:

```
Economists attributed the jump in tourism to a strengthening
economy high consumer confidence and pent up demand among
Americans who put off travel during the recession Also
a growing middle class in China is pushing visits from that
country experts said

The state persistent drought although weighing heavily on
residents does not appear to bother travelers interested in
sunshine shopping and sightseeing

Visitors to Los Angeles are not going to care if it gets a
little brown around the edges quipped Dean Runyan a
consultant who studied the tourism economy for Visit
California report released Tuesday

Still Runyan cautioned the drought could affect tourism
in rural counties where fishing and boating are popular pastimes

Some experts worry that a bigger issue is the US dollar
strength compared to other currencies
```

Comment: Please try to ask a dedicated question instead of dumping all what you have

Comment: Functions do not belong in header files.

Comment: Not sure what `myToUpper` function supposed to do, convert the whole string to upper case or just one char as it is now, but then which char? You never pass char to it.

Comment: I'm in a 111 class, and the functions were put there because our teacher told us to. As I said earlier I have no clue what I'm doing however I do that it is only supposed to convert the first character in every word.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether you'll be able to use STL constructs for your project/assignment (if not, my apologies for having a bad instructor), so if not, then this will be for the benefit of any visitors who want a /sane/ approach to solving this problem, as a light sprinkling of the STL makes this incredibly simple:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>

int main() {
    //Container for the frequency data
    std::map<char, size_t> char_map;

    //Read the whole file into memory, for efficient reads
    std::string file_contents;
    std::ifstream file("project2.dat");
    size_t length;
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    length = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    file_contents.resize(length);
    file.read(file_contents.data(), length);
    //If you don't have a C++17 compiler, use this instead:
    //file.read(&file_contents.front(), length);

    //Iterate over the file, which we've stored in memory.
    for(char c : file_contents)
        //Omit if we're including spaces
        if(c != ' ')
            ++char_map[char(std::toupper(c))];

    //Display the results
    for(auto const& pair : char_map) {
        std::cout << "Occurrences of \'" << pair.first << "\': " << pair.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Note: this approach is only safe for single-byte text encodings. It is not safe for any multi-byte text encoding.

The output of this program will be the frequency of each character in the file in lexicographical order, case-insensitive.

```
//Input:
I watched as nobody attended my fourth grade birthday party.

//Output:
Occurrences of '.': 1
Occurrences of 'A': 6
Occurrences of 'B': 2
Occurrences of 'C': 1
Occurrences of 'D': 6
Occurrences of 'E': 4
Occurrences of 'F': 1
Occurrences of 'G': 1
Occurrences of 'H': 3
Occurrences of 'I': 2
Occurrences of 'M': 1
Occurrences of 'N': 2
Occurrences of 'O': 3
Occurrences of 'P': 1
Occurrences of 'R': 4
Occurrences of 'S': 1
Occurrences of 'T': 6
Occurrences of 'U': 1
Occurrences of 'W': 1
Occurrences of 'Y': 4
```

It's much simpler if we're reading from *standard-in*. This /can/ be adapted to be used with files, but it'll probably be slower than the approach I used above, for particularly large files.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>

int main() {
    std::map<char, size_t> char_map;
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
        for(char c : line)
            if(c != ' ')
                ++char_map[char(std::toupper(c))];

    for(auto const& pair : char_map) {
        std::cout << "Occurrences of \'" << pair.first << "\': " << pair.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not safe for any other text encoding"? You are using the console output encoding for cout, std locale for toupper, the file's encoding, and the compilation execution-charset encoding for literals, but none are likely to be the ASCII encoding/character set. If they are all compatible over the relevant data, it works. I guess you could say that it requires a single-byte encoding since the file is being analyzed one byte at a time.

Comment: @TomBlodget I've updated the post to be more accurate in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not yet covered containers in C++

So you want to count frequencies of letters in the file you read.

The only thing you need now an array where all the letters can be represented.

```
int freq[MAXCHARS] = {0};  // e.g. 26
```

Assuming we are working with ASCII characters they start at ASCII value 65 which is 'A'

In C++ arrays start at index 0, so you need a way to map the character to the array 'freq'

Calculate the index by subtracting 'A' from the character, you will then get the index 0 for 'A', 1 for 'B' etc.

Text can probably be mixed casing so convert everything to upper case using the function `toupper()`

```
ch = std::toupper(ch);  // make sure it is upper case
auto index = ch - 'A';  // calculate the index in the array
freq[index]++;          // add one for the character found
```

Now what you need to do is to read from the file one character at a time and identify if it is a letter
if so, then update the array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

const int MAXCHARS = 26;

int main(/*int argc, char* argv[]*/)
{
  using namespace std;

  int freq[MAXCHARS] = {0};

  std::ifstream f("yourfile");
  do
  {
    auto ch = f.get();
    if (std::isalpha(ch))
    {
      ch = std::toupper(ch);
      auto index = ch - 'A';
      freq[index]++;
    }
  }
  while (!f.eof());

  for (int i = 0; i < MAXCHARS; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << char(65+i) << ":" << freq[i] << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;    

  return 0;
}
```